# TabControl with Alignment=Bottom and Appearance=Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Does anyone know if there's a way to fix this issue in .NET/WinForms with the Visual Studio designer?

Basically, if you take a blank form and add a TabControl and then set the Alignment property to Bottom and Appearance property to Buttons (or FlatButtons), the TabControl doesn't have a panel to work with.  I can't add any controls to the TabPage at all.  Is there a work-around for this?  I have a nested TabControl that I want to use bottom/button tab appearance and I can't get this to work at all.  I suppose I could use standard buttons with panels that I toggle the visibility on, but that's less than ideal.

[image]

Bonus question:

Why when I set the Alignment to Right or Left (Appearance = Buttons) is there such a huge gap between the tabs and the actual panel in the Tab Page?

[image]

Thank you!

EDIT: Using .NET 4.0 w/ VS2012

Comment: **SLAP** (jk).  Yeah I know, I know...  I've tried adopting it, and I have for a few things.  The fact is, I can be a lot more productive with WinForms (when it works - since it takes me forever to figure out simple things in XAML) and this is a fairly old project I'm working on that isn't likely to change anytime soon.  Thanks for the comment, though :)

Comment: These are known Windows problems.  Windows 7 fixed the Alignment property.  But Appearance still won't work in Windows 8 when the alignment isn't Top.  You'll have to make do with Normal appearance.

Answer (score -1):

Appearance property = Button is the issue. Modify it to Normal.

Comment: I'm aware - the question is specifically asking how to make  it work with Appearance=Button